# URL is not permitted by the application configuration

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

To give a quick test I downloaded php sdk from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

then I created a facebook App with following configuration

```
App Domains : example.com.np
Site URL    : http://example.com.np
```

I changed the following lines on facebook-php-sdk/examples/with_js_sdk.php as below

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(

'appId'  => 'ChangedThisToMyAppId',

  'secret' => 'ChangedThisToMyAppSecretValue',

));
```

but when I run this file on live server I get following error

```
Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

I believe I have set the App Domains and Site URL properly but why is this error occuring. I have also tried changing Site URL to `http://www.example.com.np` still no luck.

Can any one light me on this? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I dont know why my app was not working but this problem was solved after I **deleted that app** completely and created a new app at facebook. May it was problem with facebook. I am not sure ...

Answer (score 0):

if you have live website upload all sdk files to that webserver and fill your own domain name and site url.
If you do not have server then use

localhost as domain name

Site url is the place where we implement facebook login.

example

App Domains : bikal.com

Site URL    : http://bikal.com/index.php

Comment: I have uploaded the files on live server. I think my question states that. But I am getting error.

Comment: Did u replaced example.com by your domain name ?

Comment: yes I did !! I am not allowed to post the domain of the project I am working on . So I gave example.com.np as an example of my situation.